# Deleting defined variables or assign within group

Tags: l3regex

This is a followup to Egregs answer in the question [Expandable math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283788/89976), The code is included here as an MWE.

It would be a great help if I could somehow delete all previeously defined variables, or assign them only within a group. Another possibility could be simply to allow reassigning of variables with the same name. As of now, this gives an error on attempting to do so.

Edit: I've added some lines to the MWE at the bottom, which tries to set the variables within a group(but still makes them global), attempting to redefine a variable, which gives an error on trying to print it.

Error given:

> ./root.tex:122: Missing \endcsname inserted.
>    
>                     \cs_set_nopar:Npx 
>   l.122 }

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex,siunitx,xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_runart_variables_seq
\prop_new:N \l__runart_variables_temp_prop
\tl_new:N \l__runart_variables_matte_tl
\tl_new:N \l__runart_variables_item_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\definevariable}{mm}
 { % #1 is the name, #2 is the key-value set
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_runart_variables_seq { #1 }
  \prop_clear:N \l__runart_variables_temp_prop
  \keys_set:nn { runart/variables } { #2 }
  \prop_gclear_new:c { g_runart_var_#1_prop }
  \prop_gset_eq:cN { g_runart_var_#1_prop } \l__runart_variables_temp_prop
 }

% syntactic sugar
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__runart_gput:nn
 {
  \prop_gput:Nnn \l__runart_variables_temp_prop { #1 } { #2 }
 }

% keys
\keys_define:nn { runart/variables }
 {
  value .code:n = \__runart_gput:nn { value } { #1 },
  value .value_required:n = true,
  unit .code:n = \__runart_gput:nn { unit } { #1 },
  unit .value_required:n = true,
  name .code:n = \__runart_gput:nn { name } { #1 },
  name .value_required:n = true,
  sisetup .code:n = \__runart_gput:nn { sisetup } { #1 },
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\matte}{m}
 { % #1 is the expression to output
  \tl_set:Nn \l__runart_variables_matte_tl { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_runart_variables_seq
   {
    \regex_replace_all:nnN
     { ##1 }
     { \c{runart_variable_use_matte:n} \cB\{ ##1 \cE\} }
     \l__runart_variables_matte_tl
   }
  \tl_use:N \l__runart_variables_matte_tl
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\formal}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__runart_variables_matte_tl { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_runart_variables_seq
   {
    \regex_replace_all:nnN
     { ##1 }
     { \c{runart_variable_use_formal:n} \cB\{ ##1 \cE\} }
     \l__runart_variables_matte_tl
   }
  \tl_use:N \l__runart_variables_matte_tl
 }


\cs_new_protected:Nn \runart_variable_use_matte:n
 {
  \use:x % it's necessary to expand the optional argument
   {
    \SI
     [\prop_item:cn { g_runart_var_#1_prop } {sisetup}]
     {\prop_item:cn { g_runart_var_#1_prop } {value}}
     {\prop_item:cn { g_runart_var_#1_prop } {unit}}
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \runart_variable_use_formal:n
 {
  \prop_item:cn { g_runart_var_#1_prop } { name }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
{
\definevariable{a_car}
 {
  name=a_{\mathrm{car}},
  value=20,
  unit=\metre\per\second,
 }
\definevariable{v_car}
 {
  name=v_{\mathrm{car}},
  value=40,
  unit=\metre,
 }
\definevariable{t_car}
 {
  name=t_{\mathrm{car}},
  value=2,
  unit=\second,
  sisetup={color=red},
 }



\[
\matte{
  a_car=\frac{v_car}{t_car}
}
\]
}
Trying to redefine a variable:
\definevariable{t_car}
 {
  name=t_{\mathrm{car}},
  value=2,
  unit=\second,
  sisetup={color=red},
 }
\[
\matte{
  t_car
}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, note that the code has been slightly changed (there was a contradictory usage of variables); nothing that can influence your current problem, though.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the problem with global declaration; you can do `\definevariable` everywhere and this would clear the already assigned values, in case you use a previously used name. Note that it would be easy to define variables just in the scope of an `equation` environment, but not for `align` or `gather`.

Comment: I would need to print the variables both in text and in `align`, `gather` etc. Well, if it doesn't work it isn't the end of the world. Just means that I'll have to make sure all my variables are unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redefining variables should be possible; here's a polished up version, with a hint for error checking.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex,siunitx,xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_runart_variables_seq
\prop_new:N \l__runart_variables_temp_prop
\tl_new:N \l__runart_variables_matte_tl
\tl_new:N \l__runart_variables_item_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\definevariable}{mm}
 { % #1 is the name, #2 is the key-value set
  \seq_if_in:NnF \g_runart_variables_seq { #1 }
   {
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_runart_variables_seq { #1 }
   }
  \prop_clear:N \l__runart_variables_temp_prop
  \keys_set:nn { runart/variables } { #2 }
  \prop_gclear_new:c { g_runart_var_#1_prop }
  \prop_gset_eq:cN { g_runart_var_#1_prop } \l__runart_variables_temp_prop
 }

% syntactic sugar
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__runart_put:nn
 {
  \prop_put:Nnn \l__runart_variables_temp_prop { #1 } { #2 }
 }

% keys
\keys_define:nn { runart/variables }
 {
  value .code:n = \__runart_put:nn { value } { #1 },
  value .value_required:n = true,
  unit .code:n = \__runart_put:nn { unit } { #1 },
  unit .value_required:n = true,
  name .code:n = \__runart_put:nn { name } { #1 },
  name .value_required:n = true,
  sisetup .code:n = \__runart_put:nn { sisetup } { #1 },
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\matte}{m}
 { % #1 is the expression to output
  \__runart_matte_or_formal:nn { runart_variable_use_matte:n } { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\formal}{m}
 {
  \__runart_matte_or_formal:nn { runart_variable_use_formal:n } { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__runart_matte_or_formal:nn
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__runart_variables_matte_tl { #2 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_runart_variables_seq
   {
    \regex_replace_all:nnN
     { ##1 }
     { \c{#1} \cB\{ ##1 \cE\} }
     \l__runart_variables_matte_tl
   }
  \tl_use:N \l__runart_variables_matte_tl
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__runart_use_prop:nn
 {
  \prop_if_in:cnTF { g_runart_var_#1_prop } { #2 }
   {
    \prop_item:cn { g_runart_var_#1_prop } { #2 }
   }
   {
    \str_case:nn { #2 }
     {
      {value}{999999}
      {unit}{\metre}
      {name}{undefined}
     }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_empty:nTF { f }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \runart_variable_use_matte:n
 {
  \use:x % it's necessary to expand the optional argument
   {
    \SI
     [\__runart_use_prop:nn { #1 } {sisetup}]
     {\__runart_use_prop:nn { #1 } {value}}
     {\__runart_use_prop:nn { #1 } {unit}}
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \runart_variable_use_formal:n
 {
  \__runart_use_prop:nn { #1 } { name }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\definevariable{a_car}
 {
  name=a_{\mathrm{car}},
  value=20,
  unit=\metre\per\second,
 }
\definevariable{v_car}
 {
  name=v_{\mathrm{car}},
  value=40,
  unit=\metre,
 }
\definevariable{t_car}
 {
  name=t_{\mathrm{car}},
  value=2,
  unit=\second,
  sisetup={color=red},
 }
\[
\matte{
  a_car=\frac{v_car}{t_car}
}
\]
\[
\formal{
  a_car=\frac{v_car}{t_car}
}
\]
\[
\matte{
  a_car=\frac{v_car}{t_car}
}
\]
Trying to redefine a variable:
\definevariable{t_car}
 {
  name=t_{\mathrm{car}},
  value=2,
  unit=\second,
  sisetup={color=blue},
 }
\[
\matte{
  t_car
}
\]
Trying to redefine a variable, but forgetting the value:
\definevariable{t_car}
 {
  name=t_{\mathrm{car}},
  unit=\second,
  sisetup={color=blue},
 }
\[
\matte{
  t_car
}
\]
\end{document}
```

In case a value has been forgotten, it's possible to use a fallback one (and maybe to add a more sensible error message).

[image]

Using local assignments doesn't seem the best approach; for instance, you could use `\definevariable` in an `equation` environment (or variant thereof), but not in `align`, because each cell of an alignment forms a group.

Comment: Thank you so much, you have really helped me out. When I get the time, I'll read up on `l3regex` and the like, so I don't have to bother you with these questions. It's just very different from LaTeX-syntax.